# Turning a single column of rows with blanks to a single column of rows without blanks, in a new place, dynamically?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

In Microsoft Excel 2016, how can I turn a single column of string rows with blanks (the whole row is not blank), into a single column of rows such that it updates when the data in the dataset updates?

[image: The explanation of the problem]

The image basically describes the problem. Note that the blanks are not always one row long, and the blanks differ in length.

I have looked at some functions that may give me what I need, but they are locked behind Office 365.
For e.g. the SORT, the SORTBY and the FILTER functions are only available in the Office 365 version of Excel, so I have to do it without them.

Comment: What about joining the cell contents together concatenate() or & then substitute() to get rid of spaces then left(), mid() and right(0 to split the characters out.

Comment: `AGGREGATE` is a good way to go if you don't have Office 365.

Comment: @BigBen was aggregate() available in Excel 2016? I'm not sure...

Comment: @SolarMike not sure either but the linked thread also proposes a non-`AGGREGATE` solution. Edit: appears so from the [`AGGREGATE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) docs, depending on how much one can trust MSFT docs.

Comment: `AGGREGATE()` function is available from `Excel 2010`+ onwards, while `SMALL()` is probably from `Excel 2003`+ onwards a quick search on google or asking the google will let know this, also try the search `StackOverflow` there are ample of solutions with these two functions given by **[Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner)** Sir. **[INDEX() + SMALL()](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4851590+INDEX+SMALL)** & **[INDEX() + AGGREGATE()](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4851590+INDEX+AGGREGATE)**